# What does "went after corruption as hard as... " mean?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

Edward Snowden on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/snowden/status/679692055271096321) commented,

> Imagine if the government went after corruption as hard as it goes after guys who run filesharing sites. Priorities.

What did Edward Snowden mean?

Comment: It means the government is not going after corruption as hard as it goes after guys who run filesharing sites like Edward Snowden. The government don't know what priorities are.

Comment: Thanks. I miss understand the meaning of "go after", and now the meaning is much more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read: "go after" as prosecute.

> Go after
>
> *phrasal verb of go*
>
> 1. pursue or hunt down (someone).
>
> [google: go after](https://www.google.com/search?q=Go+after&oq=Go+after&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i64l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Read: "Imagine if" as hypothetical. Snowden is inviting us to envision a world where prosecuting corruption was considered as important as prosecuting filesharing.

Comment: Why is it: "*If ... went after corruption*" ? (for the sake of making the answer more complete)

Comment: @Mari-LouA relentlessly reasonable as always.